# Definition of the Krull dimension of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a topological space. It is **irreducible** if it can not be written as a union of $U$ and $V$ where $U,V$ are proper closed subsets of $X$.

A **chain of irreducible closed subsets of $X$** is a sequence
$$
Z_0\subsetneq Z_1\subsetneq\cdots \subsetneq Z_n\subset X
$$
where each $Z_i$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$. For each of the chain, its **length** is either $\infty$ or the integer $n$, and we define the **Krull dimension** $\dim(X)$ to be the supremum of lengths of chains of irreducible closed subsets of $X$.

I am a little bit confused about the definition. For each chain, do we allow $Z_n$ to be $X$ (say, $X$ is an irreducible closed subset)? If the only irreducible subsets of $X$ are the one-point sets and itself, is its dimension $0$ or $1$?

Thank you!

Comment: It would help you, and us, if you can explicate what "irreducible" means for you...

Comment: @paulgarrett Sure, added.

Comment: It depends. If $X$ is irreducible, then it may count as an irreducible closed subset. Otherwise, not.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for pointing it out. Yes.

Comment: For the record, if you use the definition that $X$ is irreducible if and only if there are $A,B\subsetneq X$ closed sets such that $A\cup B=X$, then you allow $\emptyset$ to be irreducible, and therefore you really want to require that the first element of the chain is non-empty.

Comment: Oh good point, I do allow $Z_0$ to be $\varnothing$... The definition of dimension I am reading is ambiguous. I probably shouldn't allow.

Comment: With the assumption that I have mentioned, you obtain that in a topological space $X$ where the only irreducible (non-empty) subsets are $X$ and the points there are exactly three mutually exclusive cases: 1) $\dim X=-\infty$ (or $-1$, depends on the convention) and $X=\emptyset$; 2) $\dim X=1$, there is a closed point and there are two points; 3) $\dim X=0$, all points are dense and $X\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Usually when we talk about dimension of a topological space, this is done outside of algebraic geometry and we are using either one of the inductive dimensions or the Lebesgue covering dimension. I've changed the title because I found this misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we allow the case $Z_n$ being the whole space. If you think of a spectrum of an integral domain, then $Z_n$ is the whole spectrum and it corresponds to the zero ideal, which is prime in this case and therefore should be counted.

When the only irreducible subsets are points and the space itself then the dimension is $1$, not $0$. Note that in this case points are closed because closure of an irreducible subspace is also irreducible. I do not know an explicit example of such a space but for sure it must be T1 but neither sober (because the whole space is irreducible and has no generic point) nor Hausdorff for a Hausdorff spacs to be irreducible, it must be one-point space because if there are two points then there are two open subsets separating them, which is not possible because in an irreducible space, nonempty subsets intersect non-trivially.

P/s: thanks to a comment of RobArthan, an example for such spaces is any infinite set endowed with the cofinite topology.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that not many common places are irreducible (except for the one-point sets).

Comment: Isn't the Zariski (cofinite) topology on the real line an example of a space (with more than one point) whose only irreducible subsets are points and the space itself?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the Zariski topology. I will check it. @RobArthan

Comment: @RobArthan, tks, cofinite topology on any infinite space would work.

Comment: No, nonempty subsets only.